# Delay on screen wake

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note-2, wakelock

When I push my power button to wake my device it takes 1-4 seconds for the screen to turn on and show the lock screenp. I have seen that others have solved the issue by turning off power-saving mode and auto-brightness, but I have done both and neither fixes it. What could be causing this lag?

I just updated my Note 2 to Android 4.3 although I have been experiencing these symptoms for a long time before that. I am using ADW Launcher.

Comment: The Galaxy S4 does exactly the same half the time. It seems to be down to Touchwiz and its incredible amount of bloat and lag. The launcher will make no difference. I rooted and installed the 'google edition' ROM and the lag is 100% gone at all stages so it seems to be Touchwiz I'm afraid. You could download a 3rd party lock screen and see if it helps, but I'd imagine not.

Comment: TouchWiz has been slightly problematic since Android 4.1; but it is much worst from Android 4.2. Like RossC said, try another Android widget.